# How to use ffmpeg to encode ogg audio files?

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, encoding, ogg, vorbis

I want to convert the following simple `oggenc` command to use `ffmpeg` instead:

```
oggenc -b 8 input.wav -o out.ogg
```

From the [ffmpeg libvorbis wrapper doc](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-codecs.html#Options-14), it says,

> The following options are supported by the libvorbis wrapper. The oggenc-equivalent of the options are listed in parentheses.
>
> ```
>   b (-b)
> ```
>
> Set bitrate expressed in bits/s for ABR. oggenc -b is expressed in kilobits/s.

But I just don't know how to apply it to `ffmpeg`, I've tried,

```
ffmpeg -i input.aac -c:a libvorbis -b 8 out.ogg
ffmpeg -i input.aac -c:a libvorbis b 8 out.ogg
ffmpeg -i input.aac -c:a libvorbis=b:8 out.ogg
```

but none is working as expected.

**UPDATE:** What I want to know is how to "translate" the options listed in ffmpeg (libvorbis wrapper) doc into ffmpeg command. I can get away with `-ab` switch to do the transcode, but I don't think it is the *libvorbis wrapper specific* options. So if you provide the answer, please provide the demo specifying all the following options as well.

```
b (-b)

q (-q)

minrate (-m)

maxrate (-M)

iblock
```

Comment: If you want such a low bitrate why not use a more suitable format such as Opus?

Comment: @LordNeckbeard, is Opus widely supported, even on older version of Windows?

Comment: I don't use Windows often, and I don't know what Windows version(s) you are referring to, but I'd guess the answer is "no" for native support of both Opus **and** Vorbis unless you use VLC or some other sane player.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The answer is in your question:

```
oggenc option    corresponding ffmpeg option
-b               -b:a
-q               -q:a
-m               -minrate
-M               -maxrate
```

#### Example command

```
ffmpeg -i input.aac -c:a libvorbis -b:a 8k output.oga
```

If your desired value of `8k` fails then use a higher bitrate or lower your audio sampling rate with `-ar`, such as `-ar 8000`.

#### Encoder and muxer info

You can see additional info and the single private option that is specific to this encoder with:

```
ffmpeg -h encoder=libvorbis
```

You can also get info about the muxer/output container format:

```
ffmpeg -h muxer=ogg
```

Comment: Thanks. It'd be great if a full example of command-line is provided. And BTW, the answer is not in my question, as I don't know how you know `minrate (-m)` is just `-minrate`, not `-minrate:a` whereas `b (-b)` somehow magically becomes `-b:a`. Neither `ffmpeg -h encoder=libvorbis`, nor `ffmpeg -h muxer=ogg`, or the online-doc provide that info.

Comment: The documentation was probably written before some options got the ability to use stream specifiers. If you just use `-b` then `ffmpeg` will tell you to use `-b:a` instead.

Comment: Use **32k** or **64k** because "8k" won't work and throw: "encoder setup failed
Error initializing output stream 0:0 -- Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:0 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height"

Answer (score 6):

This works for me:

`ffmpeg -i test.aac -c:a libvorbis -b:a 64k test.ogg`

I don't think 8kb/s is a valid value, but I could be wrong. :-)

Comment: 8kb/s is a valid value for vorbis/oggenc. that's why I'm using it, and your answer is not. Welcome abroad, BTW.